# How can I efficiently generate all N-bit values with M set bits, and the corresponding bit-reversed values?

Tags: python, algorithm, binary, bit-manipulation

I'm using the following Python code to generate all values with `popcount` set bits among `bits` total bits:

```
def trailing_zeros(v):
    return (v & -v).bit_length() - 1

def bit_permutations(popcount, bits):
    if popcount < 0 or popcount > bits:
        pass
    elif popcount == 0:
        yield 0
    elif popcount == bits:
        yield (1 << bits) - 1
    else:
        v = (1 << popcount) - 1
        while v < (1 << bits):
            yield v
            t = v | (v - 1)
            v = (t + 1) | (((~t & -~t) - 1) >> (trailing_zeros(v) + 1))
```

For example, `bit_permutations(5, 3)` yields `0b00111, 0b01011, 0b01101, 0b01110, 0b10011, 0b10101, 0b10110, 0b11001, 0b11010, 0b11100`.

For each of the above values, I also need the value with the order of bits reversed, e.g. `0b11100, 0b11010, 0b10110, 0b01110, 0b11001, 0b10101, 0b01101, 0b10011, 0b01011, 0b00111`. Currently I'm calling a separate `reverse` function each time a value is generated by `bit_permutations`:

```
def reverse(v, bits):
    assert bits <= 16
    v = ((v >> 1) & 0x5555) | ((v & 0x5555) << 1);
    v = ((v >> 2) & 0x3333) | ((v & 0x3333) << 2);
    v = ((v >> 4) & 0x0F0F) | ((v & 0x0F0F) << 4);
    v = ((v >> 8) & 0x00FF) | ((v & 0x00FF) << 8);
    return v >> (16 - bits)
```

However that seems inefficient. Is it possible to modify `bit_permutations` so that it directly generates each permutation along with its reverse, rather than using a separate, less-efficient `reverse` function?

Comment: Do you want to generate (a, reverse(a)) and then, after some other elements, (reverse(a), a)? Or just (a, reverse(a)) with no repetition?

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI I think either way would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible to modify the `bit_permutations` function to directly generate each permutation along with its bitwise reverse. We can achieve this by maintaining a separate mask for the reversed bits while iterating through the permutations.

```
def trailing_zeros(v):
    return (v & -v).bit_length() - 1

def bit_permutations(popcount, bits):
    if popcount < 0 or popcount > bits:
        pass
    elif popcount == 0:
        yield 0, 0
    elif popcount == bits:
        yield (1 << bits) - 1, (1 << bits) - 1
    else:
        v = (1 << popcount) - 1
        while v < (1 << bits):
            reverse_v = int(format(v, f'0{bits}b')[::-1], 2)
            yield v, reverse_v
            t = v | (v - 1)
            v = (t + 1) | (((~t & -~t) - 1) >> (trailing_zeros(v) + 1))

# Example usage
popcount = 3
bits = 5
for perm, reverse_perm in bit_permutations(popcount, bits):
    print(f"Original: {format(perm, f'0{bits}b')}, Reverse: {format(reverse_perm, f'0{bits}b')}")
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe "bitwise reverse" was the wrong term. I need to calculate the values with the order of bits reversed, not with the bits individually inverted (which it looks like your `reversed_mask` is intended to do). For example, the reverse of `1000` is `0001`, not `0111`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```py
from sympy.utilities.iterables import multiset_permutations


def bit_permutations(popcount, bits):
    s1, s2 = ["0"] * popcount, ["2"] * popcount
    s1[:bits], s2[-bits:] = ["1"] * bits, ["1"] * bits

    for p1, p2 in zip(multiset_permutations(s1), multiset_permutations(s2)):
        yield "".join(p1), "".join(p2).replace("2", "0")


for p1, p2 in bit_permutations(5, 3):
    print(f"{p1=} {p2=} {int(p1, 2)=} {int(p2, 2)=}")
```

Prints:

```
p1='00111' p2='11100' int(p1, 2)=7 int(p2, 2)=28
p1='01011' p2='11010' int(p1, 2)=11 int(p2, 2)=26
p1='01101' p2='11001' int(p1, 2)=13 int(p2, 2)=25
p1='01110' p2='10110' int(p1, 2)=14 int(p2, 2)=22
p1='10011' p2='10101' int(p1, 2)=19 int(p2, 2)=21
p1='10101' p2='10011' int(p1, 2)=21 int(p2, 2)=19
p1='10110' p2='01110' int(p1, 2)=22 int(p2, 2)=14
p1='11001' p2='01101' int(p1, 2)=25 int(p2, 2)=13
p1='11010' p2='01011' int(p1, 2)=26 int(p2, 2)=11
p1='11100' p2='00111' int(p1, 2)=28 int(p2, 2)=7
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of making these recursively.

```
  import functools
  
  @functools.cache
  def bit_permutations(popcount, bits):
      if popcount < 0 or popcount > bits:
          return []
      elif popcount == 0:
          return [(0, 0)]
      elif popcount == bits:
          m = (1<<bits)-1
          return [(m, m)]
      else:
          left  = [(m, n<<1) for m, n in bit_permutations(popcount, bits-1)]
          right = [(m|1<<(bits-1), n<<1|1) for m, n in bit_permutations(popcount-1, bits-1)]
          return left + right
```

This function is not a generator though. It is slightly more efficient that the original generator plus the `reverse` function. It can be turned into a generator, but it needs memoization for efficiency, and it doesn't make a lot of sense to memoize a generator.